# Slotted cleats for SPD shoes

Tags: pedals, shoes, spd

Does anyone make a cleat, or an adapter that would accommodate a cleat, that has a slot for use with old style caged pedals that use toeclips & straps, that fits 2-bolt SPD style cycling shoes?

Comment: There are double-sided pedals that have "mountain" SPD clips on one side and a toe clip platform on the other.  Mostly just used on exercise bikes, though, since the strap will tend to drag at spots using SPDs.

Comment: Yeah, they're not hard to [find](http://www.sportsmith.net/ItemForm.aspx?Item=P00106). The question is why would you want one...

Comment: I believe the OP is asking whether there's a slotted cleat that would allow the same shoe to be used on both SPD pedals and on a separate bike with caged platform pedals.

(My guess would be no, since the slot would weaken the cleat substantially.)

Comment: My guess is demand for them would be very low. The exit strategies of clips and clipless are quite different. Few people adapt quickly enough between them. Many that try have helped show Darwin was correct.

Comment: I've never seen anything like that. My question is, why the hell do you *want* the old-style cleats? There's a reason nobody uses them anymore. I used to have them, and there's no way I'd go back.

Answer (score 2):

I did find these

http://www.yellowjersey.org/tocleat.html

[image: Tocleat for Look shoes]

And Yellow Jersey is exactly the kind of shop you'd expect to find that stuff. 
The one in the image is for Road shoes, but I think could easily be adapted to 
SPD shoes with some work with a dremel tool.

They say they will make a custom cleat for just about any shoe. You do realize that because SPD shoes have the cleats embedded in the outsole, you'll need to at least grind a slot in the tread of the shoe.

It occurs to me that just grinding the slot in the tread of the shoe and then 
grinding off the tabs on a standard SPD cleat would get you pretty close to 
what is required.